Is it better to add a single listener to the list container or should I just add a listener for each item in the list?
I guess it's more efficient to just have one listener but, is it something I should care about? Does it depend on any circumstances?
I have implemented it with multiple listeners as it is simpler for me, but I would like to do it the best possible way.

Hi Luis - the technical term for adding a listener to the container is "event delegation" - there's more about it on SO that you can search for. The question given as the duplicate goes into some of the benefits but is can be a matter of opinion as well. And, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Thank you so much, I dont understand how that didn't came up in my search. I'll try to research more next time.
